# how to find this string through regex in python

Tags: regex

```
b'[{"Name":"ACAJUTLA ; SV ; SVAQJ","Code":null}]
```

and the required ans is: - `ACAJUTLA ; SV ; SVAQJ`

Comment: You can find a string through regex by writting first a pattern

Comment: yes i am asking you the pATTERN WHICH CAN SOLVE THIS

Comment: That data looks like JSON, in which case it would be preferable to parse it with a JSON parser rather than a regex (somewhat easier to implement and a great deal more robust and maintainable)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a site where you can request code. You can ask for help if you have issue with your code, but can't ask others to code for you.

Comment: As mentionned @Aaron, a JSON parser is certainly the best approach rather than reinventing the wheel using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, please note that it does not handle escaping of " inside the string you're looking for. (e.g. if the output should have " inside it this will not work well).

```
In [8]: m = re.search(r'"Name"(\s*):(\s*)"(?P<name>[^"]+)"', '''b'[{"Name":"ACAJUTLA ; SV ; SVAQJ","Code":null}]''')

In [9]: m.groupdict()
Out[9]: {'name': 'ACAJUTLA ; SV ; SVAQJ'}
```

Comment: You can fix the escaping if necessary by adding a negative look-behind assertion for the square brackets inside the name group. (verify that it doesn't have a single backslash)